# For a BCS superconductor is definig the anomalous Green functions unique or is there some choice?

Tags: superconductivity

Hopefully, a easy question, but I am wondering if there is any particular reason to define the anomalous Green function in one form rather than another.

For instance, I have seen it defined as both (for a singlet SC with no center of mass momentum):

$$F(t)=<T(\hat{c}_{p\uparrow}\hat{c}_{-p\downarrow})>$$

or

$$F(t)=<T(\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{p\uparrow}(t)\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{-p\downarrow})>$$

Moreover, taking the form of the first one, I have seen the adjoint defined as either the second expression above, or as this expression but with the order of the operators switched.

Does the order even matter in the end as long as you are consistent?

Comment: No, it does not matter. It is just a matter of naming convention.